# mysqli constructor returns null

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to write a db util class using the singleton pattern. My problem is that the "connection" object is always null. The connection settings are correct. What could i be doing wrong ? Also, i am relatively new to php development. What method should i use to figure out what's wrong ? Code follows.

```
   class DBUtil {
        public $connection = NULL; //mysqli_connection object
        private static $instance = NULL;

        private function _constructor($conn){
            //$this->connection = mysqli_connect(TagMetroConfiguration::getConfigurationValueFor("db_servser_name"), TagMetroConfiguration::getConfigurationValueFor("db_username"), TagMetroConfiguration::getConfigurationValueFor("db_password"), TagMetroConfiguration::getConfigurationValueFor("db_name"));
            $this->connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "toor", "testdb");
        }

        public static function getInstance(){
            if(DBUtil::$instance == NULL){
                try{
                    DBUtil::$instance = new DBUtil();
                }catch(Exception $ex){
                    throw new Exception("Unable to create DB Instance");
                }
            }

            return DBUtil::$instance;
        }
}
```

Comment: Well actually, the singleton pattern looks too complicated to you, but that's not a problem at all: Just don't use singletons. You don't need them in PHP. In your case you only need a global variable for the database connection. - But if you feel like copy and paste, [the PHP manual has a code example for the Singleton Pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton) (not that this makes anything better, don't use it ). [Who needs singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4595964/367456).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor function should be named `__construct` (notice two underscores).

Also, in your constructor, you have one parameter, `$conn`. When you call `new DBUtil()`, you are not providing that input parameter, so perhaps it's calling the default contructor, not your custom one.

If you want the input parameter `$conn` to be optional, try `__construct($conn = null)`.

Or try calling it as `new DBUtil(null)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private function _constructor($conn)   ??
```

should this be

```
private function __construct($conn)
```

Comment: Also might want to set the default value to null, as your not passing a $conn variable when instantiating the object. private function __construct($conn = null)

Answer (score 2):

There should be two underscores `__` (`__construct`).

Answer (score -1):

You should do like this :

```
class DBUtil {

        private static $instance;

        private function _construct(){
            $this->$instance = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "toor", "testdb");
        }

        public static function getInstance(){
            if(!isset(self::$instance){
                try{
                    self::$instance = new DBUtil();
                }catch(Exception $ex){
                    throw new Exception("Unable to create DB Instance");
                }
            }

            return self::$instance;
        }
```